# Showing Hidden Row in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using some code based on the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHC5C/). The intention is to show more information when the user clicks the "Show Extra" link.

The problem that I'm having is that when the link is clicked on all but the bottom row of the table the hidden element is shown briefly and then closes.

I am populating my table using template strings in javascript. Here is the code that I use to add rows to the table:

```
this.addRecordToTable = function(bet, index, id){
console.log(index);
console.log($.data(bet));
var butId = id.toString();

if (bet.bookies == null){
    bet.bookies = "";
}

if (bet.bet == null){
    bet.bet = "";
}

var newRow = `
<tr>
    <td>${bet.date}</td>
    <td>${bet.bookies}</td>
    <td>${bet.profit}</td>
    <td><button id=${butId}>Delete</button></td>
    <td><a href=\"#\" id=\"show_${index}\">Show Extra</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=\"5\">
        <div id=\"extra_${index}\" style=\"display: none;\">
            <br>hidden row
            <br>hidden row
            <br>hidden row
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
`



console.log(newRow);
console.log("#"+butId);

$(newRow).appendTo($("#betTable"));
$("#"+butId).click(
    function()
    {
        if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) 
        {
            var rec = new Records();
            rec.removeRecordAt(index);
            $("#betTable tbody").remove();
            var c = new Controller();
            c.init();
        }

    });

$("a[id^=show_]").click(function(event) {
    $("#extra_" + $(this).attr('id').substr(5)).slideToggle("slow");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

}

EDIT:

I had to change `$("a[id^=show_]").click` to `$("a[id=show_"+index).click...`, as the event handler was being added to each element every time I added a new element. Thanks to @freedomn-m.

Comment: please create a working example of your problem so we can help you better ( share all relevant code in a snippet )

Comment: Your best bet will be to try to create this without the template.  If it then works, you can work back to find the difference between your template-generated code and your working-code.  As you already have working code in the fiddle, you should be able to look at what your template is generating to see why it's not generating the same code.

Comment: `$("a[id^=show_]")` - this code adds a new event handler to every *existing link* as well as the new one as it's not ID specific and all your `a`'s match the selector.   This is also the problem with using 'toggle' instead of 'show'.  Change to `$("a[id^=show_]", newRow)` or `$("a#show_" + ${index} + ")`

Comment: Add an `alert` or `console.log` inside the `a` click handler to see when it's being called.

Comment: I actually changed to `$("a[id=show_"+index).click` and now it works. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$("a[id^=show_]")
```

adds a new event handler to *every existing link* as well as the new one as it's not ID/context specific so all the show `a`'s match the selector.

You need to add the context (`newRow`) or use the existing variable(s) as part of the loop that are already defined, eg:

```
$("a[id^=show_]", newRow)
$("a#show_" + index)
```

(or any other variation that works).

---

An alternative would be to use even delegation for the dynamically added elements, eg:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[id^=show_]", function...
```

in which case you'd only need to define/call the event once and it would be fired for new elements (ie put that outside the new row loop).